# Django not logging all errors on production

Tags: django, error-handling

My Django app is only properly logging and emailing errors when Debug=True.

On production, I'm only getting 'Invalid HTTP_HOST header' errors in both the log file and my inbox. **Every other error is not logged in the django log nor is it emailed to me**.

I've tried some things with this test request:

```
def test(request):
    logging.debug('debug test message')  // Always appears in log file
    from django.core.mail import mail_admins
    mail_admins('test error', 'test error via call to mail_admins()') // Always arrives in my inbox just fine
    raise Appointment.DoesNotExist  // When Debug=False (both locally and in production), does not appear in log file or in inbox.
```

My logging settings for both local and production:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(module)s %(process)d %(thread)d %(message)s'
        },
        'simple': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s'
        },
        'csv_formatter': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s;%(asctime)s;%(message)s'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'null': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.NullHandler',
        },
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'verbose'
        },
        'default': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'maxBytes': 1024 * 1024 * 50,
            'backupCount': 10,
            'formatter': 'csv_formatter',
        },
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler',
            'formatter': 'verbose',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        '': {
            'handlers': ['default'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'asyncio': {
            'level': 'WARNING',
        },
        'django.request': {
           'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
           'level': 'ERROR',
           'propagate': True,
        },
        'django.security': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}
```

How do I make sure all Django errors are logged and emailed in production (when Debug=False)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25370868/django-error-invalid-http-host-header-u-run-myprojectname-gunicorn-sock

Comment: @Jisson, my question is not about getting invalid host header error emails. It's about getting none of the errors that actually matter! :)

Comment: Have a look [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/logging/#default-logging-definition) for the default logging configuration that django uses. Note that this is merged with your logging config. In this case if you want `raise Appointment.DoesNotExist` to be logged to the console when debug is `False`, you will have to override the console handler's `filters` as it currently requires `debug` to be true. Try to set it to just `[]`. About the admin mailing: In your function, if you remove `mail_admins()` and set debug to `True`, does `raise Appointment.DoesNotExist` send an email?

Comment: Have a look at the documentation : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/logging/#id3
I presume that with `DEBUG=True`, you fire the empty logger that calls the default handler.
With `DEBUG=False`, you only trigger the HTTP (django.request) and Security (django.security) errors.
What if you create a `django` logger ?

Comment: not really a solution here but for monitoring something in production I'd recommend using monitoring tools like Sentry

Comment: I could not reproduce this. Which version of Django are you on?

Comment: @aaron Django 3.2

Comment: I'm on Django 3.2.11 and could not reproduce it. Can you reproduce it locally, or only on your production server?

Comment: @aaron Thanks for trying. It happens both locally and in production.

Comment: Can you reproduce it with a new project and share it on GitHub?