# get domain name from django request

Tags: python, django, dns, django-request

I had a website with domain `www.example1.com`, and recently i have pointed another domain dns `www.example2.com` to same server that contains www.example1.com, so both `www.example1.com` and `www.example2.com` serves the same code but domain name should be different, and I want to get domain names from django request as below

```
def homepage(request):
    domain = request.META['HTTP_HOST']
    if domain == 'www.example1.com':
       return HTTPResponseReredirect('/new/')
    elif domain == 'www.example2.com':
       return HTTPResponseReredirect('/old/')
```

So based on the domain name i want to redirect user to different web pages, but each and every time i used `request.META['HTTP_HOST']` the output was an IP address `127.0.0.1:8001` as below

```
META:{'HTTP_ACCEPT': ‘text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8’,

'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING': 'gzip, deflate, sdch, br',
'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
'HTTP_CONNECTION': 'close',
'HTTP_COOKIE': 'sessionid=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx; ',
'HTTP_HOST': '127.0.0.1:8001',
'HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS': '1',
'HTTP_USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36',
'PATH_INFO': u'/',
'QUERY_STRING': '',
'RAW_URI': '/',
'REMOTE_ADDR': '127.0.0.1',
'REMOTE_PORT': '41280',
'REQUEST_METHOD': 'GET',
'SCRIPT_NAME': u'',
'SERVER_NAME': '127.0.0.1',
'SERVER_PORT': '8001',
'SERVER_PROTOCOL': 'HTTP/1.0',
'SERVER_SOFTWARE': 'gunicorn/19.0.0',
```

But how to get the actual domain name ?

Answer (score 3):

request.META['HTTP'] shows current domain name on server, or IP address if domain name do not tied.

---

For example i have this function on my project

```
def test(request):
   return HttpResponse("{}".format(request.META['HTTP_HOST']))
```

1. What show`s me test function on local server

   [image]
2. What show`s me test function on remote server with domain name *aut0parts.site*
   [image]

I assume you testing your code in local server, that`s why your output is 127.0.0.1:8001. If you set domain name to your server I think everything will work :)

Comment: Nope, i am testing directly in server, the output i pasted above was from server django http request, that's what i am confused about and why it was not showing the domain name

Comment: You set the domain on remote server? What web-address on your project?

Answer (score 2):

Are you using nginx in front of gunicorn?

As per these two SO questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25708262/2189058) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22027177/2189058), having a bad 'HTTP_HOST' in your request.META strongly suggests misconfiguration of your nginx config.

The relevant response from both posts:

> Seems like
>   `proxy_set_header Host $http_host` should be changed to
>   `proxy_set_header Host $host` and `server_name` should be set
>   appropriately to the address used to access the server.

Comment: yes i am using nginx, gunicorn and supervisord in combination

Comment: Yep, so check the nginx config to make sure the http_host is being passed through for each domain correctly.