# Django Disallowed Host

Tags: python, host

I've been seraching the forums and also tried what most answers advised to.

Error Msg:

> DisallowedHost at /
>   Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'theile-albrecht.de'. You may need to add u'theile-albrecht.de' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
>   Request Method: GET
>   Request URL:    http://theile-albrecht.de/
>   Django Version: 1.11.15
>   Exception Type: DisallowedHost
>   Exception Value:
>   Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'theile-albrecht.de'. You may need to add u'theile-albrecht.de' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
>   Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/http/request.py in get_host, line 113
>   Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
>   Python Version: 2.7.12
>   Python Path:
>   ['/home/django/django_project',
>    '/home/django/django_project',
>    '/usr/bin',
>    '/usr/lib/python2.7',
>    '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
>    '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
>    '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
>    '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
>    '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
>    '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages']
>   Server time:    Sat, 4 Aug 2018 08:33:11 +0000

That's what I did:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['theile-albrecht.de']
```

I also tried:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*'] aswell as localhost
```

After each try I restarted the server but didnt work

Comment: I suggest you run your `django-admin shell` and chech if `django.conf.settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS` is what you've set.

Comment: Have you set `proxy_set_header Host $host` in your nginx config?

Comment: Not sure what that means, i'm not that deep into it. Website was running for 7 Months straight, but after i tried to reface letsencrypt for the second time this error came up.

All it did is:

./letsencrypt-auto certonly --standalone -d theile-albrecht.de

Maybe i did something wrong?

Comment: @TheileAlbrecht You've to add `Host` header in your nginx config. [thins might help you to set it up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21970750/error-invalid-http-host-header-webapps-gunicorn-sock). Or can you us the relevant  nginx.conf please?

Comment: @MadhanVaradhodiyil https://textuploader.com/dzby9